# Unable to install snowflake-connector-python on Windows

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone please help me install Snowflake connector for python so that through python we can execute the query in snowflake.

I am using python version 3.7.4, and the below is the error I receive when trying to install with `pip`:

```
(base) C:\Users\a662919>pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A8B0597948>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/snowflake-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A8B02E7308>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/snowflake-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A8B02E7688>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/snowflake-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A8B0599788>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/snowflake-connector-python/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001A8B0599848>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/snowflake-connector-python/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake-connector-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for snowflake-connector-python
```

Comment: Hi Brajesh! Please read up on [writing a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Answer (score 1):

The error `Connection to pypi.org timed out.`, assuming your internet connectivity is otherwise functional, likely indicates (among other possibilities) that you either have a proxy in use that the `pip` command is not utilizing, or an administrative firewall rule is in place that prevents you from making connections to the Python package repositories from within your organization.

If the problem is simply that of a proxy, [try specifying your web proxy URL](https://www.calazan.com/how-to-set-the-proxy-settings-in-windows-via-command-line/) explicitly in the command prompt via the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable, and then retry:

```
(base) C:\Users\a662919> set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@your-proxy-host:your-proxy-port

(base) C:\Users\a662919> pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
```

If you continue to receive the exact error despite specifying the proxy, then you may be running into a firewall rule or another form of an administrative block. Contacting your IT personnel (or equivalent) for clarification (over accessing pypi.org) would make for a good next step in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version should resolve this. Also use virtual environments if possible.